# How to prove nonstationarity of a random walk?

Tags: regression, time-series, self-study, stationarity, unit-root

Given the AR(1) model $Y_t = ϕY_{t−1} + e_t$ . I want to show if |ϕ| = 1, the process cannot be stationary. I know to prove stationary it suffices to prove either mean function or autocovariance function is not independent of time. It is my first time approaching this type of problem so I really have no clue how to approach it.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: Unfortunately I still have not made any concrete progress unless I know what h to plug in..

Comment: 1. Please [merge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your FOUR accounts ([177004](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/177004/leehom) 
[177006](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/177006/leehom)
[177009](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/177009/leehom)
[177015](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/177015/leehom) ) so you can comment in your own posts. Do not keep creating a new account every time you interact with the site 2. Please don't post comments as answers.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, it suffices to show that the Variance (the 0th-order of the autocovariance) is time dependent.

$y_{t}=y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_{t}$

$Var\left(y_{t}\right)=Var\left(y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_{t}\right)$

$Var\left(y_{t}\right)=Var\left(y_{t-1}\right)+\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}$

$Var\left(y_{t}\right)=Var\left(y_{t-2}+\varepsilon_{t-1}\right)+\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}$

$Var\left(y_{t}\right)=Var\left(y_{t-2}\right)+2\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}$

repeating this for $t$ steps:

$Var\left(y_{t}\right)=Var\left(y_{0}\right)+t\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}$

If we assume that $y_{0}$ is given:

$Var\left(y_{t}\right)=t\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}$

Which means that the variance of the process increases with time, and therefore not stationary.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you mean:

> I know to [dis]prove stationar[it]y it suffices to prove [that] either [the] mean
>   function or [the] autocovariance function is not independent of time.

But yeah that's right. So here's a hint. I would focus on the autocovariance portion. If this process is indeed stationary, then the (auto?)covariance function 
$$
\gamma_X(t+h,h) \overset{\text{def}}{=} \operatorname{Cov}(X_{t+h},X_t)
$$
shouldn't depend on time ($t$) for any lag $h$. So to disprove that, you would have to find some *particular* $h$ where it *does* depend on time.

Comment: How do I get the intuition for finding that h? Is h in terms of ϕ?

Comment: Sorry I cannot comment on posts as a newcomer.. but okay i get the hint idea just don't know where to start..should I expand Cov(Xt+h,Xt)?

Comment: @Leehom yes that could help